# Error loading Visual Studios 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Everytime i try to open Visual Studios 2012, an error message displays

" Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e25' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any idea what is wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Your machine is sick.  It needs a doctor, not a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Uninstall the Visual Studio that you have and download it from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/esn/2013-preview. It works for me perfectly.